# z-order for MessageBox with LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

We are using a LINQPad script for some lightweight monitoring on several processes on several servers.
When a problem is detected, we use a MessageBox:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(...)
```

Unfortunately, this often appears behind the main LINQPad window.
The Show() method has an override that takes a 'Win32Window' parameter: "Displays a message box in front of the specified object".
Is there a way to get the LINQPad window object?

Other suggestions for getting the MessageBox near the front of the desktop z-order?

Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get LINQPad's main window handle, I doubt you could reliably parent a window to it, because LINQPad's host UI runs in a separate application domain with its own message loop.

A simple workaround might be to write your own version of MessageBox.Show that brings up a custom window that's always on top, or one with with a timer that looks for the LINQPad process window and ensures it's always above it.

Another option is this:

```
Util.ReadLine ("About to upload - Press Enter to continue");
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  By "your own version of MessageBox.Show that brings up a custom window " are you suggesting a new assembly loaded, somehow, by the LINQPad script?

Comment: Write it in "My Extensions"